# How to execute different REST API requests in parallel in C# on .NET Core?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

**Problem Statement**

I need to send multiple API calls at one shot.

I have three different API endpoints as shown below, and all these need to be called together almost as quickly as possible. It's all independent of each other.

```
public async Task<string> GetA(string a)
{
}

public async Task<string> GetB(int a)
{
}

public async Task<string> GetC(int a, string a)
{
}
```

**What I tried**

I was trying like this:

```
public async Task CallMultipleAPIs()
{
    await GetA("");
    await GetB(1);
    await GetC(1, "");
}
```

How to implement parallelism here?

Comment: Do not await the tasks directly but await all tasks together using Task.WhenAll.

Comment: Do you need call from c# or other?

Comment: @Goniometr Only in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is concurrency (not parallelism - i.e., multiple threads).

Concurrent asynchronous code is done by using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task CallMultipleAPIs()
{
  var taskA = GetA("");
  var taskB = GetB(1);
  var taskC = GetC(1, "");
  await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC);
}
```

Comment: To clarify: As soon as `GetA()` makes an I/O request (like a network request) control passes back to `CallMultipleAPIs()` and then `GetB()` is called, etc. This is "concurrent" in that all of this happens on the same thread. It is not "parallel", since "parallel" means running code on different threads.